# How to view http traffic in jetty http client?

Tags: logging, jetty, cometd

How to view http traffic in jetty http client ?

I tried apache logger format

to set 'org.eclipse.jetty' to TRACE level,

still unable to view http traffic, similar to apache http client wire logging.

Is there any way to log http traffic in jetty http client ?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Jetty's `HttpClient` with the logging level `org.eclipse.jetty.client=DEBUG`, and any logging framework should log `HttpClient`'s activity.

Alternatively, if you use the default Jetty logging system, you can configure a `jetty-logging.properties` in the class-path, with the same logging level described above.

Lastly, if you use the default Jetty logging system, you can specify this system property on the command line: `-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.client.LEVEL=DEBUG`.

Note that in this way Jetty's `HttpClient` does not log just HTTP traffic, but all the activity of `HttpClient`'s implementation.

There is no logging category for just HTTP traffic because the exact headers that are sent to the server could be decided at the very last moment just before writing them to the network -- this is particularly true for content headers (but also for authentication), so it would require collaboration from different Jetty modules.

Comment: I am basically trying to mock cometd response, to test error scenarios for diff meta channels, i thought if I could capture http traffic with fiddler or something, I could manipulate it, at realtime, i am trying to find a way to mock cometd response to test code..

Comment: Are you writing an implementation of a CometD client that is not supported by the CometD project?